# Is BroadcastReceiver nescessary for a wifi scan?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-wifi

This is my code below and it works fine, when i walk into a wifi enviroment im able to receive all the wifi BSSID and when i walk out, it returns null. however i saw examples that uses broadcast receiver, isit nescessary for wifi scanning? Just want to make sure im doing it right

```
 public static String getBSSID(Context context){ /
    WifiManager wifiManager;
    List<ScanResult> results;
    List<String> ids = new ArrayList<>();
    wifiManager = (WifiManager)  context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

    String essidPrefix = MainFragment.configuration.getEssidPrefix();
    String bssid = null;

    results = wifiManager.getScanResults();
    for(ScanResult scanResult : results){
        String scanWifi = scanResult.SSID;
       if(scanWifi.startsWith(essidPrefix)){
          ids.add(scanResult.BSSID);
          bssid = TextUtils.join(",",ids);


       }

    }

    StatusActivity.addMessage(bssid);
    return bssid;
```

Answer (score 1):

As per android documentation, you register a broadcast listener for SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION, which is called when scan requests are completed, providing their success/failure status. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-scan
So in case you want to handle your success and failure result.

As for using the `getScanResult()` goes, the docs clearly mentions that the returned scan results are the most recently updated results, which may be from a previous scan if your current scan has not completed or succeeded. This means that you might get older scan results if you call this method before receiving a successful `SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION` broadcast. So this is the reason why you need BroadcastReceiver and in case of not using it you might see stale or not current results.